# Javascript - How to display SessionStorage obj in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have object data in sessionStorage and I want to display them as a list in HMTL via loop. How do I Achieve this?

SesionStorage.cart data stringified:

```
[{"itemName":"WS: FaceShield, 10pcs pack","itemPrice":0,"itemQuantity":"1"},{"itemName":"Faceshield, 1 pc","itemPrice":0,"itemQuantity":"1"}]
```

What I want to do now is display them on a list after parsing them as JSON Object again.

Comment: Write a loop that creates `<li>` elements and appends them to the DOM.

Comment: Please, read [ask], [edit] and create a [mcve] of your best try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have

```
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Here's a suggestion how to do it in JavaScript by using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) into a [Web API DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) that can be later [ParentNode.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) -ed into an `UL` HTMLElement:

```
// Let's define our array
const arr = [
  {"itemName":"WS: FaceShield, 10pcs pack","itemPrice":0,"itemQuantity":"1"}, 
  {"itemName":"Faceshield, 1 pc","itemPrice":0,"itemQuantity":"1"}
];

// Store it into LS...
localStorage.arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
// Read it from LS
const LS_arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.arr);


// Create a helper for new elements... 
const ELNew = (sel, attr) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), attr || {});


// Loop the array and create LI elements
const LIS = LS_arr.reduce((DF, item) => {
  DF.append(ELNew('li', {
    textContent: `Name: ${item.itemName} Price: ${item.itemPrice}`
  }));
  return DF;
}, new DocumentFragment());

// Once our DocumentFragment is populated - Append all at once!
document.querySelector("#myUL").append(LIS);
```